# Why do I get Gold stars from some bitizens in their dream job?

Tags: tiny-tower

Some of my floors in tiny tower have gold stars and some silver, I know this relates to bitizens in their dream jobs, but there's no obvious reason why some are gold, any ideas?

Comment: I played tiny tower vegas a while back, so this may or may not be the same. All employees with dream jobs gave 1 silver star to that job/floor, and having all 3 employees in their dream job on a floor gave you the gold star.

Comment: @Katustrawfic, silver stars are given for Bitizens that have a skill level less than 9. Gold stars for Bitizens with skill level = 9.

Answer (score 1):

If the bitizen has a skill level of 9 and you give him/her their dream job you will get a gold star, but if the bitizen has 8-0 skill in that category then you will get a silver star

However i don't really know if the gold star does anything.

Comment: The gold star indicates that the bitizen has a skill level of 9, as you said. Having a star in general means you get 2x the amount of goods for the price of only one set. You also get a discount based on the sum of the skill level of each worker.